# Image not extending width of table cell

Tags: html, css, image

I have an image that is in a cell of a table.  The table set has a width of 604px and a height of 379px.  I set the image css to be width: auto and height: auto.  This isn't stretching the image to occupy the full space of the cell.  If I set the image to width: 100%, then it stretches the cell to a width that I don't want.  Any advice on how to solve this issue?  CSS and HTML below.  The td cell has the style cellfive in the CSS and the image is imgsecond.

Thanks.

```
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
<meta name="keywords" content="declassified information" />
<style type="text/css">    
.style1
{
    background-color: #c1b7a6;
    width: 339px;
    padding-left: 1.5em;
    height: 88px;
}
.style2
{
    background-color:#7f6d53;
    width: 339px;
    padding-left: 1.5em;
    height: 166px;



}
.style3
{
    background-color:#5e513d;
    width: 339px;
    padding-left: 1.5em;
    height: 125px;
}
.style4
{
    outline: #5c492d solid 2px;             
    width: 100%;   
    height: 100%;     
}
    .style5
    {
        border-right: 2px solid #5c492d;
        width: 604px;
        height: 379px;

    }
    .style6
    {
        padding-left: 1.5em;
        padding-right: 1.5em;
    }
    .style7
    {
        background-color: #7f6d53;
        outline: #5c492d solid 2px;
    }
    .style8
    {
        padding-left: 1.5em;
        padding-right: 1.5em;
        width: 943px;
        height: 254px;
    }
    .img
    {
       width: 100% !important;
       height: 100% !important;

    }
</style>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
<p></p>
 <div align="center" >
<table class="style4" cellpadding= "0px" cellspacing= "0px">

 <tr>
<td rowspan="3" align="left" valign="top" class="style5" >
<div style="height:100%; width:100%">
    <asp:Image ID="imgMain" runat="server" CssClass="img"  />
    </div>
</td>

   <td   align="left" valign="top" class="style1">  <asp:Image ID="imgText" runat="server" />
  </td>
   </tr>

  <tr>
  <td  align="left" valign="top" class="style2" >
    <asp:Label ID="lblSum" 
        runat="server" Text="Label" ForeColor="Black" Font-Names="KozGoPr6N-Bold"></asp:Label>
   </td>
 </tr>

  <tr>
   <td  align="left" valign="top" class="style3"> <asp:Label ID="Label5" 
        runat="server" Text="Refine Your Results By" ForeColor="#F9B92D" 
        Font-Names="KozGoPr6N-Bold"></asp:Label>
          <br />
          <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStyle" runat="server" Width="30%" >
          </asp:DropDownList>
          <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlColor" runat="server" Width="30%">
          </asp:DropDownList>
          &nbsp;<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlStyleQ" runat="server" Width="30%" >
          </asp:DropDownList>
          &nbsp;<br />
          <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlApplication" runat="server" Width="30%" >
          </asp:DropDownList>
          <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCollections" runat="server" Width="30%">
          </asp:DropDownList>

      &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
   </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: width: 100%; works, but .img{  width: 100%; } is not assigned to any image/tag.

Comment: When I use width 100%, it stretches my cell to more than width: 604px and height: 379px.  That's why that .img tag isn't assigned to anything because I tested it and when I saw how it was stretching out the cell I changed the styling of the image.

Comment: I updated the code to try and fix this issue.  The height isn't working now.

Answer (score 0):

try using

```
style="width:inherit; height:inherit"
```

Might work

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if

```
width: inherit; height: inherit;
```

will work, otherwise you need to do something in your cell with Width and Height. :)

Answer (score 0):

Modify the css rule -

```
.imgsecond
    {
       width: auto;
       height: auto;
    }
```

to -

```
.imgsecond
    {
       width: inherit;
       height: inherit;
    }
```

This should fix the problem. Tested on a sample and works well.

Comment: I tried using this, but I'm still not seeing the image stretch across the entire space of the cell.